# Where can I find test vectors for ChaCha20 (trying to understand Wikipedia example)?

Tags: stream-cipher, chacha

I was playing around with stream ciphers an found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) Wikipedia ChaCha20 page (the ChaCha variant). What I'm lost with is how to test this code. There are no testvectors anywhere on that page and I cannot find any. I wrote the following C code:

```
#define ROTL(a,b) (((a) << (b)) | ((a) >> (32 - (b))))
#define QR(a, b, c, d) (            \
    a += b,  d ^= a,  d = ROTL(d,16),   \
    c += d,  b ^= c,  b = ROTL(b,12),   \
    a += b,  d ^= a,  d = ROTL(d, 8),   \
    c += d,  b ^= c,  b = ROTL(b, 7))
#define ROUNDS 20

void chacha_block(uint32_t out[16], uint32_t const in[16])
{
int i;
uint32_t x[16];

for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i)    
    x[i] = in[i];
// 10 loops × 2 rounds/loop = 20 rounds
for (i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i += 2) {
    // Odd round
    QR(x[0], x[4], x[ 8], x[12]); // column 0
    QR(x[1], x[5], x[ 9], x[13]); // column 1
    QR(x[2], x[6], x[10], x[14]); // column 2
    QR(x[3], x[7], x[11], x[15]); // column 3
    // Even round
    QR(x[0], x[5], x[10], x[15]); // diagonal 1 (main diagonal)
    QR(x[1], x[6], x[11], x[12]); // diagonal 2
    QR(x[2], x[7], x[ 8], x[13]); // diagonal 3
    QR(x[3], x[4], x[ 9], x[14]); // diagonal 4
}
for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    out[i] = x[i] + in[i];
}
}

void main(){
    const char* constant = "expand 32-byte k";
    uint32_t inwhole[16];
    inwhole[0] = ((uint32_t*)constant)[0];
    inwhole[1] = ((uint32_t*)constant)[1];
    inwhole[2] = ((uint32_t*)constant)[2];
    inwhole[3] = ((uint32_t*)constant)[3];

    inwhole[4] = 0;//key[0];
    inwhole[5] = 0;//key[1];
    inwhole[6] = 0;//key[2];
    inwhole[7] = 0;//key[3];
    inwhole[8] = 0;//key[4];
    inwhole[9] = 0;//key[5];
    inwhole[10] = 0;//key[6];
    inwhole[11] = 0;//key[7];

    //Zero counter and nonce
    inwhole[12] = 0;
    inwhole[13] = 0;
    inwhole[14] = 0;
    inwhole[15] = 0;

    uint32_t out[16];
    chacha_block(out, inwhole);
    printHex((char*)out2,16*4);
    //This prints out:
 //76b8e0ada0f13d90405d6ae55386bd28bdd219b8a08ded1aa836efcc8b770dc7da41597c5157488d7724e03fb8d84a376a43b8f41518a11cc387b669b2ee6586
}
```

I could not find any test vectors to validate this first keystream block against.
Also I found it confusing that is the next keystream block meant to be generated by passing the previous output back to the `chacha_block` function?
Also is this cipher meat to be used to xor the keystream blocks with the data (this was not explicitly mentioned in the article)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChaCha20 cipher had been specified by an "informational" RFC - [RFC-8439](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8439/) as a reference for use in Internet protocol specifications. The document contains some test vectors.